# Naming threads in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I thought it was always recommended to name your threads to make it easier to debug later on.

In my SpringBoot project I now used the `@Async` notation and later on a `TaskExecutor`, but could not find a way to name my threads.

Is there a way to do that, or not really done in the Spring abstractions?

Comment: Working with Java for 20+ years, I never heard of that "always recommendation".

Comment: @GhostCat Well said!

Comment: Sorry yeah, "always" does not make sense of course! Rather for the important ones ? Or is there no real value in naming threads?

Comment: Yeah, whatever. Stepping back and thinking a second for what you are doing or not doing is always a a good thing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TaskExecutor` in Spring is a functional interface that extends directly from Java's `Executor`. According to the documentation:

> An object that executes submitted Runnable tasks. **This interface
>   provides a way of decoupling task submission from the mechanics of how
>   each task will be run, including details of thread use**, scheduling,
>   etc.

What this means is that it is not possible (and should not be required) to name your thread as you are not responsible for starting and managing it. That said, for debugging purposes, if you want to provide some name, you should do that to the thread pool itself by setting `threadNamePrefix` and/or `threadGroupName` properties.

Comment: You can not completely name the thread, but you *can* add a prefix with `setThreadNamePrefix`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use thread prefix conf property in task executor configuration, or  you can use `ThreadFactory` if prefix is not enough

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my_thread_prefix");
    executor.setThreadFactory( new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("my-thread-%d").build())
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: I used only `setThreadNamePrefix` method to set name prefix, but its not working. Why do we need next method calling from factory builder set?